# jsonify is not sending data back to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I'm trying to do a simple client/server communication using AJAX, but I can't get my response from the server. I m sending dummy data back to the client (for testing purposes), it still doesn't work.

**[Assumed problem]**

The odd part is, by looking at the browser's console, the `console.log('start')` and `console.log('end')` show **really** quickly and then disappear. Also, the same may be true for the responses, I don't have time to see them. Is it because of the `post` being run inside the `onclick` event?

I have an input, that once triggered, will run a function as follow:

**Html**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <textarea name="text" class="text-editor", spellcheck="false", autocomplete="off", autofocus>##Type sth</textarea>
   <input type="submit" id="clickme">
</form>
```

**Client side**

```
document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = showdownText;

function showdownText(){

    console.log('start')
    
    $.post('/_get_payload', {
        text: textEditor.value
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('success')
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('fail')
    });

    console.log('end')
    
}
```

**Server Side**

```
@app.route('/_get_payload', methods=['POST'])
def get_payload():
    data = request.form['text']

    post = Post(text=data)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()

    print(post)

    return jsonify({ 
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@localhost",
        "id": 42
    })
```

Question: Why is it that I don't get back my payload from the server, even though I send dummy data?

Comment: I assume the form submit is reloading the page. "The odd part is, by looking at the browser's console, the console.log('start') and console.log('end') show really quickly *and then disappear*."` <= paired with the fact that you are clicking a form submit button, that tells me the page is doing a page transfer.

Comment: Try changing your `<input type='submit'` to `<input type="button"`

Comment: @Taplar it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the submit button (`<input>` or `<button>` with `type="submit"`) inside a `<form>` element, the browser will send a POST request to the server, and the page will be reloaded, that's why the content of `console.log` will disappear.

In your case, since you send the POST request with AJAX, there is no need to create a `<form>` or `<input type="submit">` element, just use this

```
<textarea name="text" class="text-editor" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autofocus>##Type sth</textarea>
<button id="clickme">Submit</button>
```

P.S. There is no need to add a comma between HTML attributes.

Comment: An alternative would be to have an event listener on my form and listen for the `onsubmit` event. It's more flexible, in case I have server forms inside my HTML. Thanks!